# How to make a Fullscreen application with Java?

Tags: java, macos, swing, fullscreen

How can I make this application fullscreen?
I know how to make it a window on my mac, however, i can't find a way to make it fullscreen so that when I press the green button (Top Left) on my mac it becomes fullscreen. My code is below, Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.frame.setTitle("Fullscreen Test");
    main.frame.add(main);
    main.frame.pack();
    main.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    main.frame.setVisible(true);

    main.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply get the the screen size and just set your frame size accordingly.

```
 Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
 main.frame.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

But, the more preferred way would be use the **Window** Object and check if the device supports the full screen or not and then by using the **java.awt.GraphicsDevice** object the set the full screen.

```
GraphicsDevice deviceObject;
Window windowObject;

try {
    deviceObject.setFullScreenWindow(windowObject);

}catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    deviceObject.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}
```

Comment: Use `setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` to maximize the frame to take up the whole screen.

Comment: That is not what full screen means though, the answer got it right.